# How to simplify structure of a monitoring software that uses the Observer pattern?

Tags: design, design-patterns, c++, architecture

I am working on a project where I have to monitor the status of an elevator. So far, my design looks like this: [image: Class diagram]

We are using a third party library to read and monitor real-time values from the elevator's logic controller. A `tag` is an integer value in a memory register of the logic controller. For example, `DM140` contains the elevator direction.

I use an adapters layer in order to keep my application domain isolated from the third party library.

In the domain, the `ElevatorDirectionMonitor` takes the `ElevatorTag` integer value, extrapolates the elevator's current direction, and then notifies its clients that the elevator's direction has changed. So far, so good.

Here's my problem: There will be a lot (a hundred or more) of types of information to monitor from the elevator, such as the current floor, whether the  doors are opened/closed, etc. If I continue this way, I will have to create one monitor class for each type of information I want to monitor (e.g. an `ElevatorFrontDoorStatusMonitor`, `ElevatorRearDoorStatusMonitor`) and each monitor associated with its own Observer interface. This means a lot of work. I've been trying to find another way to structure my application, but haven't found anything more "elegant".

The basic logic in each monitor class would be pretty much the same across the board: listen for value change on an `ElevatorTag` instance, extrapolate the information from the new tag value, and then notify the observers. The problem seems to come from the fact that each observer class must have a different interface signature (e.g. `ElevatorDirectionObserver`'s has `NotifyDirectionChanged(ElevatorDirection newDirection)` when a `DoorStatusMonitor` would rather have something like `NotifyDoorStatusChanged(DoorPosition frontOrRear, DoorStatus openOrClosed)`).

Do you think that the solution I am working on is acceptable. If not,could someone suggest which patterns I should use or investigate, or anything that could help me to simplify my design?

Comment: I don't see anything about a controller in the question.  I was assuming this design was just for monitoring, like to make a nice GUI of the elevator state for the security desk.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt is right, this software is inteded for monitoring purpose only. All the control logic of the elevator is done by a logical controller that is much more reliable than a computer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's a pretty good instinct to balk at creating one hundred very similar classes.  That's generally a sign those should be *instances* instead.  You might try something like:

```
monitors.createIntMonitor("Floor", "DM141")
monitors.createBoolMonitor("Front door open", "DM142")
monitors.createEnumMonitor("Direction", "DM140", ["Up", "Down", "None"])
// or alternately
monitors.createEnumMonitor<ElevatorDirection>("Direction", "DM140")

monitors.getMonitor("Front door open").addObserver(observer)
```

This design can easily be initialized dynamically, such as from a configuration file or database, including adding new fields, without requiring your app to be recompiled.  These kinds of changes often end up being the biggest maintenance cost if you do it statically.  It also requires a lot less copy/paste/minor changes, which is a big source of errors.

The disadvantage is you no longer get compile errors when you put a `RearDoorMonitor` into a variable expecting a `FrontDoorMonitor`.  It's also somewhat more problematic to cram multiple observers into one class, but that usually isn't the best idea anyway.

Your subscribers for a templatized enum monitor could look like this:

```
// Common interface
template <typename T>
class Subscriber
{
    public:
      virtual void receiveEvent(T t) = 0;
};

// Individual subscriber instance
class ElevatorSubscriber : public Subscriber<ElevatorDirection>
{
    public:
        void receiveEvent (ElevatorDirection direction);
};
```

Comment: I think the string approach for `EnumMonitor`s can easily leads to errors from unexperienced programmers of programmers that don't have a deep knowledge of the system.

Comment: See my edit, @MichaëlBlanchet.  We use this pattern all over the place in our code.  Works with our green hills compilers and gcc.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for Boost.Signals2. In this case, every "monitor" is just one instance of `boost::signals2::signal<void(ElevatorDirection)>`, say. And every "observer" is just some random function of the appropriate signature- like a lambda. You can just call the signal whenever you need and add/remove methods provided. No bullshit required.

The Observer pattern is not a pattern at all. It's just a class. A class you don't even have to implement.

Answer (score -1):

I would try to find a middle-ground. If there are, as you wrote, a hundred or more of types of information, the chance is high there will be a lot of similar types, with similar interface signatures. For example, instead of having an `ElevatorFrontDoorStatusMonitor` and an `ElevatorRearDoorStatusMonitor`, create `ElevatorDoorStatusMonitor`, where "Front" or "Rear" is just a parameter. If there are sensors for each floor, make the floor number a parameter.

You might end up with a dozen different types of observers, maybe more, maybe less, each one supporting a different list of "pic tags". Which of the pic tags  you can group together depends, of course, how much the operations in your program differ for the different types.